# How to show Images in Bootsfaces Datatable columns

Tags: jsf, datatable, bootsfaces

I need to show images dynamically in a data table column, I have the images in a local folder, how can I do that in Bootsfaces data table?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So, you are able to use images outside of the datatable?

Comment: in jsf you can put the images in the src/webapp/resources/<yourLibraryName>/images folder.  if you need to get them from elsewhere on the file system you will need to use a servlet or managedbean

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load images from outside of webapps / webcontext / deploy folder using <h:graphicImage> or <img> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543936/load-images-from-outside-of-webapps-webcontext-deploy-folder-using-hgraphi)

Comment: Hello guys thank you very much for the time... yes I'm able to use images outside of the datatable, the problem is inside the datatable because I need to show a diferent image for each row. The problem is showing the images in the datatable using Bootsfaces (b:dataTableColumn) I don't want to have to change to primefaces or another. Any idea??? Thank you very Much again!!!

Answer (score 2):

Simply nesting an HTML `img` tag in a `b:dataTableColumn` does the trick:

```
   <b:dataTable value="#{carPool.carPool}" var="car" class="editableCarTable">
      <b:dataTableColumn value="#{car.brand}" />
      <b:dataTableColumn label="Image">
        <img src="https://www.example.com/some.png" />
      </b:dataTableColumn>
    </b:dataTable>
```

You've mentioned the images are stored in a local folder. You'll have to make these images accessible to the web server. Usually, I do so by copying the images to `src/main/webapp/images`. Once the images are there, they've got a URL, so you can display them using this URL.

To make the image row-specific, put the URL into the row bean, so you can access it like so:

```
   <b:dataTable value="#{carPool.carPool}" var="car" class="editableCarTable">
      <b:dataTableColumn value="#{car.brand}" />
      <b:dataTableColumn label="Image">
        <img src="#{car.rowSpecificURL()}" />
      </b:dataTableColumn>
    </b:dataTable>
```

Of course, you can also use `h:graphicImage` or `b:image`. Both allow you to benefit from the resources folder Mitch mentioned above in the comment. The BootsFaces `b:image` also supports things like tooltips, a progress bar, and so on.