# Display image from String Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i have a link image saved on String Value in database ,and the image is uploaded in a folder on my localDisk( `WEB-INF\images\form.png`).

this is the folder link on the string value in database:

```
C:\projet\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\images\form.png
```

this link is saved here :

```
 @Column(name = "Logo")
    private String link_logo;
```

and this is the Graphicimage in view.xhtml:

```
  <p:column headerText="LOGO" width="10%">
                 <p:graphicImage value="#{bean.link_logo}"/> 
                </p:column>
```

thank you so much.

Comment: Your first mistake is that you saved it in deploy folder, against the advice in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18664715 which was shown to you in all your previous questions. Fix that as soon as possible. And then just save the file name `form.png` in DB, not the full path as that makes no sense. Then pick one of the options in the answer of the abovelinked duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/4543936 in order to serve it back to the client.

Comment: thank you so much Balus , i forget this link :https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile&method=getFileName

and its resolved now