# How to host and refer to static content from within your ear file

Tags: web-applications, jboss, shared-hosting, jboss5.x, appserver

We have several j2ee applications (e.g. A.ear, B.ear, C.war) running in a single jboss instance, we have a requirement to share a set of static files across these applications. So I should be in a position to access these files as http://myhost/folderA/fileA.htm or http://myhost/folderB/file.js from within my ear or war files.

How should I tell the jboss appserver (5.1.0) to look for these files, how should I deploy this static content in my `server/default/deploy` directory or the `docs` folder

Comment: Is your JBoss instance fronted by anything such as Apache HTTPD?

Comment: yes in the production stage, but doesn't during the development stage

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jboss with the Jetty server, you can re-use the `org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet`. I am sure tomcat has something similar or you can just add the jetty one (because it's a servlet, it will run on any servlet container).
Even though it's relatively easy to write it yourself, it's not because there are a bunch of things a quality implementation needs.

Take a look at the documentation of the `DefaultServlet` on how to configure it, it has many features.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to place the static files in one location and have each of your contexts (A, B, C,...) have a servlet that serves these static files.

If you can configure it to look in the right folder, you may be able to reuse an existing servlet like `DefaultServlet`. Or you may code your own servlet to serve static content: I once wrote one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132052/servlet-for-serving-static-content/132932#132932).