# Fastest way to deploy and run a Java WAR file?

Tags: java, testing, deployment, war

Is there a simple, programmatic way to quickly "deploy" and run a standard Java WAR file for local testing without having to install and configure external software packages like Tomcat or Jetty?  Ideally something like Jetty's embeddable features but specifically for WAR files.

Java 6 provides the convenient [`Endpoint` class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Endpoint.html) which makes it easy to quickly deploy and test web services, is there something similar for WAR files?  For example:

```java
AppServer as = new javax.iwish.AppServer("localhost", 8080);
as.deploy("/", new File("path/to/my.war");
as.start();
```

Comment: What's wrong with embedded Jetty? There is no need to install and configure it, just drop some jars into classpath.

Comment: I'd use Tomcat (Jetty should work the same). If you only need it for local testing, just download the ZIP and unpack... no need for any installation and/or configuration, simply start it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Light Java servlet container for development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186521/light-java-servlet-container-for-development)

Comment: Perhaps using ANT to deploy in Tomcat and using HttpUnit to verify if it is working as expected?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I asked too soon, it looks like [Jetty does exactly what I need](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedding-jetty.html):

```java
Server server = new Server(8080);
server.setHandler(new WebAppContext("foo.war", "/"));
server.start();
```

Remarkably close to my dreamed up API =D

Comment: using the [maven-jetty-plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin#) is much easier and faster, you don't even need to start and stop the server in most cases.

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson: right but then you have to use maven, right?  I'm trying to reduce the number of dependencies in this project...