# jboss 6 virtual directory

Tags: java, jboss6.x, virtual-directory

I cannot find a proper way to add a directory to my app context on jboss 6. 
I'll use this mapping for static content. Can someone give me a hand on that?

Comment: can you not add the directory to the deployment archive or can you not read the files within the archive?

Comment: In fact I have static content like photos in a file server. This file server share is mapped in the jboss server as a directory... Obviously this directory is out of my app context. So I gotta map this external directory to the app context... I can do it well on tomcat 6... but I cannot do the same in jboss 6 yet.

Comment: see http://community.jboss.org/message/531424 and http://community.jboss.org/message/531424 for similar issues, I'd try to unpack the .war and map the target directory (a second time (?)) to the root or subdirectory of the resulting directory (web application).

Answer (score 3):

There are no more 'virtual directories' in JBoss 6. Apparently this went out with JBoss 5. The only available options I've found are:

1. create a blank /WEB-INF/web.xml (so like just <web-app/>) in your static content directory and make a symlink with a .war extension in your jboss deploy directory. You can also copy the directory containing the static content to your deploy directory, but I find a symlink much more useful.
2. create a webapp with a servlet that serves static content from a configured directory (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132052/servlet-for-serving-static-content))
3. if you're using a web framework like spring mvc 3, you can use the 'resources' feature to serve content for you (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456635/spring-serving-static-resources-outside-context-root))

Comment: symlink didn't work for me. I had to use external deployment. Mybe my JBoss was configured not to follow symlinks?

Answer (score 0):

The bad news is that you can serve static content only inside JBoss applications. The good news is that it is very easy to transform any folder into an application folder.

The easiest solution is to copy all your static content into your `server\default\deploy\ROOT.war` directory.

A more complex solution is the following.

- Copy the `ROOT.war` folder in the position where you want to put your
  static content.
- Rename `ROOT.war` into any name you like but it must end with `.war`,
  for instance `my_static_content.war`.
- Put all your static content into that directory.
- Enable external deploy to the folder that contains your static
  content folder. External deploy with [JBoss 6](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS6-DeployApplicationInAnExternalDirectory) and [JBoss 5](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToDeployMyApplicationInAnExternalDirectoryInJBoss-5)
- Restart JBoss
- Your content will be into the URI `http:\\localhost:8080\my_static_content\`. You have to specify the exact name of the files that you want to serve, because directory listing is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

[this thread](http://www.coderanch.com/t/436452/JBoss/JBoss-virtual-directory-jboss) helped me get static content in an external directory served up on jboss eap 5.1 without the use of links and without moving or renaming the ROOT.war folder.

note that you still have to create a directory structure that tricks jboss into serving up your content. it's not as easy as adding a <Context> child element to the <Host name="localhost"> in the server.xml file. it seems like a hack but at least it works.