# Remap image requests in a web application (tomcat) with spring for an absolute path

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring, web-applications, tomcat

i'm trying to find a way remap a path to an absolute one in order to retrieve images stored in the server filesystem, i'm also using spring mvc but the `<mvc:resource>` can't map absolute paths, and i can't find a nice way to do this with spring controllers

i.e. I need to map all the image requests from /images/** to /root/var/img/**, in this way when a client browser try to load an image of the page, every images stays in the path above mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new context with `docBase` referencing to your folder (`/root/var/img`) It should look like this:

```
<Context path=”/images” docBase=”/root/var/img/” ... >
</Context>
```

Refer to Tomcat context configuration documentation for more details (e.g., for Tomcat 6: [Apache Tomcat Configuration Reference: The Context Container](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html)).

Introduction to this document lists possible places where **context** elements can be defined.

**EDIT**

As I mentioned in comments, Spring-specific way to do this without creating any new context seems to be using [RedirectView](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html) (link to Spring v2.5 JavaDoc). According to JavaDoc:

> "View that redirects to an absolute, context relative, or current
>   request relative URL, by default exposing all model attributes as HTTP
>   query parameters."

**EDIT2**

It seems I've misunderstood RedirectView purpose, which is a good old URL redirection. Thus,  answer by @Jens should be more appropriate (+1). I still wonder if there's an existing standard solution in Spring (what I originally thought RedirectView would do..) It's not like there's much code to write, but still :)

**EDIT3**
After reading more on this topic, I found out that `<mvc:resources>` is able to do this (i.e., mapping resource using not only relative path, or classpath), you just need to correctly configure **location** using **file:** prefix . In fact, there's already answer on SO that explains exactly what you need to do: [Spring : serving static resources outside context root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456635/spring-serving-static-resources-outside-context-root)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but if possible i would prefer to not create a new context, a servlet based solution would be better for me...

Comment: @Gnappuraz Ahh, I see. What about Spring's [RedirectView](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html) (link to v2.5 JavaDoc)? JavaDoc states: "View that redirects to an absolute, context relative, or current request relative URL, by default exposing all model attributes as HTTP query parameters."

Comment: the only standard solution i found is the <mvc:resources> tag, that allow this remap but only for relatives paths.

Comment: @Gnappuraz: I've read more on <mvc:resources>, and updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if I am getting that right but I think the common way to do that is to set up a controller which is mapped on the requests to /images/:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/images/")    
public void fetchImage(@RequestParam String id, HttpServletResponse response)
```

Then the controller can load the requested image from a configured directory like "/root/var/img" and write it the the OutputStream of the response. E.g:

`org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(fileInputStram, response.getOutputStream())`

In addition you have to set the correct mime type etc. in the response.

Jens

Comment: yes, i'm just trying to do something similar, with this controller

@RequestMapping(value="/images/")
public void fetchImage(@RequestParam String id, OutputStream output)