# Packaging requirejs optimized files in war

Tags: requirejs, gradle, war

In a large web application, I'm using requirejs amd modules so that the scripts themselves are modular and maintainable. I have the following directory structure

```
web
 |-src
    |-main
       |-java
       |-resources
       |-webapp
          |-static
             |-scripts
             |-styles
             |-images
          |-static-built    //output from r.js. not checked into git
          |-WEB-INF
```

During build js and css are optimized using r.js into static-built folder. Gradle is the build tool.

Now the problem: The jsps refer to the scripts in static/scripts folder and this is how i want when working locally. However when building war, I want the static files to be served from static-built folder. The important thing is the source jsp should not have to change to serve the optimized files from static-built folder.

Two options that I have are: a) the gradle build while making war should include static-built instead of static. b)include static-built in addition to static and using tuckey urlrewrite pick the resouce from static-built rather than static.

What best practices are the community following in similar scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

We've setup the server to have a runtime profile (dev, qa, prod, etc) read from a system property which determines some settings based on it. When running in production profile we serve the optimized files from the WAR. In development we serve the non-minified and non-concatenated files directly from the filesystem outside the application context.

Files are structured according to the official [multipage example](https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage).

Configuring serving files depends on your chosen backend solution. Here's an example for [spring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5456762/1630906).

Alternatively, r.js can [generate source maps](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#sourcemaps) and those will help with development as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this question is outdated already, but I had a kind of similar problem.

I had similar project structure, but with the only difference - I've split the project into 2 modules:

- one of them (let's call it **service**) was java-module for back-end
- the second one contained only js and other stuff related to front-end (let's call it **ui**).

Then in Gradle build 'assemble' task of the **service** depends on 'assemble' task of **ui** AND another custom task called '**pre-assemble**'. This '**pre-assemble**' task was copying the optimized js files to place where I wanted them to be.

So, basically, I've just added another task that was responsible for placing all the optimized js files in the proper place.