# Accessing file system resource in <resource mapping="" location=""

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring application where I want to take my static resources from a simple file system `(D:/.../..)`.

Could I do something like

```
mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="d:/../.. .css, ...js"
```

Or if there is any other way I could achieve this.

However, I need to do this only in Spring configuration file.

Comment: Let's have a look at my answer. May it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes

You can read files from file system like

`Resource resource = appContext.getResource("file:c:\\testing.txt");`.

Please refer full example from MkYong [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-resource-loader-with-getresource-example/). And if you are creating web application then you should load appContext like:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext appContext;
```

Comment: I don't have to use bean, actually I need to add .css into my jsp. And this .css is residing in filesystem. I need to do it from applicationContext.xml only and use key in jsp file directly.

Comment: Hi,

In spring configuration file I have given, context:Property-placeholder location="file:D:\resources\application.properties" I've STATIC_RESOURCES_JS_CSS_URL in my application.properties. But, it is not getting resolved in mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="#{STATIC_RESOURCES_JS_CSS_URL}"

How to do that. Any Idea??

Comment: try this `<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="file:/absolute/path/to/image/dir/"/> `. We need to provide path to dir for files. Not complete path of file. One more thing either pass `/` or `\\` to provide path.
Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456635/spring-serving-static-resources-outside-context-root

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) to read your properties file from either *classpath* or *WEB-INF* or from *file system* adding below configuration to your *applicationContext.xml* file:

**A. File in Classpath:**

```
<bean id="dbProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:db.properties" />
</bean>
```

The keys defined in the `db.properties` file can be read using `${key name}`.

**Example:** Consider, your properties file contain

```
 jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName
```

then you can read this property using below command

```
<property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
```

---

**B. File in WEB-INF:**

When your properties file in under **WEB-INF** directory, then you just add below code snippet under `dbProperties` bean & it'll starts looking your properties file in the WEB-INF directory of the application.

```
<property name="location" value="WEB-INF/db.properties" />
```

---

**C. File on File System:**

When you want *to read file from file system* then just add below code in `dbProperties` bean.

```
<property name="location" value="file:///D:/database/db.properties" />
```

---

***NOTE:*** You can either use **`file:///`** or **`file:`** in **`case C`**.

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Resource res=new ClassPathResource("Yourfile");
```

you can read the file as it is.