# Serve static files with jax.ws

Tags: java, web-services, static-files

I'm building a web front end to monitor the state of a SOAP service.

Is there any way to serve static files with jax.ws? For example `Endpoint.publish("/static", new SomeStaticFileHandler())` where any requests to /static just serve the corresponding static file in my folder? Inside the static file I would like to query the state and update the page with AJAX calls.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to [serve static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132052/servlet-for-serving-static-content) is to add a custom servlet to the web.xml.

As for the hack you want to try: serve any file type, with any content-type? It will not work, I believe. Perhaps you can serve XML files if they follow a predefined schema -- JAX-WS implementation classes return objects, not strings or streams. These objects are serialized to SOAP/XML using the schema and binding. You'd need to parse the files into objects and then return to JAX-WS runtime... and you'll get a SOAP envelope over the file content anyway.

> Inside the static file I would like to
>   query the state and update the page
>   with AJAX calls

This doesn't sound like a static file to me. This is a dynamic method serving XML or JSON. The simplest answer is still a servlet.

[JAX-RS](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html) (RESTful Java API) is a viable alternative too.

Comment: Thanks, I don't like the crazy XMLs that are needed for servlet... But guess now I have to learn servlets to mix these two :).