# How to tell web.xml that it should not handle .htc files and so leave them to the web server?

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml, vaadin

How to tell web.xml that it should not handle .htc files and so leave them to the web server?

How can I do that ?

I am using Vaadin and it's servlet gets all requests, but I really need to serve a .htc file to fix IE(Dawn you Microsoft) corners and make them look better.

How to do that ?

Vaadin Servlet Mapping

> ```
> >     <servlet-mapping>
> >         <servlet-name>vaadinServlet</servlet-name>
> >         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
> >     </servlet-mapping>
> ```

Servlet

```
>   <servlet>
>       <servlet-name>vaadinServlet</servlet-name>
>       <servlet-class>com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.GAEApplicationServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
>           <description>
>           Application widgetset</description>
>           <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
>           <param-value>web.googlemapwidget.Widgetset</param-value>
>       </init-param>   </servlet>
```

Comment: Why the PHP tag, and why would web.xml handle a .htc file in the first place?

Comment: What is web.xml? I expect web.xml to be just an xml file. An xml does nothing other than hold data.

Comment: He probably asked how to configure the servlet in web.xml. Vaadin servlet is probably mapped to all requests so you need to make an exception for it to handle .htc file using the default servlet. The choice of default servlet depends on which servlet container you are using.

Comment: Can you skow me your web.xml?

Comment: Course... it's updated in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>vaadinServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <!-- servlet-name>staticServlet</servlet-name --> <!-- removed as suggested by raymi -->
    <url-pattern>/*.htc</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Notice that the `url-pattern` for vaadinServlet is changed from `/*` to `/`, which is the default mapping. It means if no other pattern is matched then use this servlet. Here is a [quick reference](http://gigadot-blogger.blogspot.com/2010/11/url-patterns-in-servlet-mapping-by.html) I wrote about the url pattern mapping.

<del>You will need to define your static servlet. This depends on your servlet container. For tomcat,</del>

```
<!-- removed as suggested by raymi -->
<!--servlet>
    <servlet-name>staticServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet-->
```

<del>In case you do not want your staticServlet to depends on the servlet containter, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132052/servlet-for-serving-static-content/132932#132932).</del>

Comment: I think there's no need to define the static servlet for tomcat in your web.xml, since it's already defined in the default web.xml (which you can find at `<TOMCAT_DIR>/conf/web.xml`) as `default`. So you can simply map to `<servlet-name>default</servlet-name>`.

Comment: Thank you @raymi . Does the `default` servlet name exist for all servlet containers?