# Serve files from a folder different of context directory in a servlet container

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-container

I got a situation that I must serve files from different folders then the one of the context my web app is running. As an example, suppose my web app is running in a servlet context on "/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/" and I must serve files existent in "/opt/my_other_folder/". These folders can be changed in runtime by the client, so I can't simply add a new context pointing to these directories. I would like a solution that I wouldn't have to rewrite a web server only for that. Also, the product I work on is generic, so I can't have a solution specific to some servlet container.

Thanks!

Comment: Notice that my question is NOT the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132052/servlet-for-serving-static-content

Answer (score 0):

If you're only serving files, I would consider fronting your servlet container with something like Apache HTTP Server, where you could simply use its various directives to provide a "virtual directory" pointing to an easily configured location.

Otherwise, you could write and configure a standard Java servlet that would do essentially the same thing - storing the actual path in a Java properties file that would be read by the servlet.  But while this isn't a **lot** of work, it would be significantly more work that the above Apache HTTP Server solution.  This would be very similar to several of the answers posted at [Servlet for serving static content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132052/servlet-for-serving-static-content) .  Specifically, you could either use or extend upon Apache Tomcat's [DefaultServlet](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/servlets/DefaultServlet.java).  (There are some Tomcat-specific classes used in here, but they could be easily replaced with generic equivalents.)  http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html looks even closer to what you'd be looking for, and it is completely generic - while still having some additional, significant features.

Either of these options would be very generic, and not specific to any particular servlet container.

Comment: Notice that fronting my web app with an http server is not an option, since the user will have the option of add / edit / delete a service folder. For the same reason, the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132052/servlet-for-serving-static-content aren't suittable for me. The post you linked is the closest to what I want, but it does seems to be rewriting an http server for me. But, even so, thanks for your answer...

Comment: Just to clarify, it's not rewriting a web or HTTP server.  The server is still handling all the low-level aspects of the request, and providing a rather nice servlet API to work with.  :-)

Comment: I may not have been so clear in what I sad. I didn't mean that would be rewriting the servlet container (which implement the servlet API). I meant it would be like rewriting a http server (as the Apache Http server, which does not implement the servlet API).