# JBoss resources location

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x

I'm trying to load a JavaScript file to my jsp file

Here is what I've tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="static/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/static/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="/WebContent/WEB-INF/static/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="WebContent/WEB-INF/static/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="/WEB-INF/static/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="WEB-INF/static/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="/USI-WEB/WEB-INF/static/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/USI-WEB/WebContent/WEB-INF/static/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="USI-WEB/WEB-INF/static/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="USI-WEB/WebContent/WEB-INF/static/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="<%=request.getContextPath() + "/static/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="<%=request.getContextPath() + "/static/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"%>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="<%=request.getContextPath() + "/WebContent/WEB-INF/static/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="<%=request.getContextPath() + "WebContent/WEB-INF/static/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"%>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="<%=request.getContextPath() + "/WEB-INF/static/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"%>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="<%=request.getContextPath() + "WEB-INF/static/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"%>"></script>
```

[image: This is my project structure]

[image: This is the file location]

And this is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>USI WEB</display-name>

  <!-- Filter to set character encoding on each request -->


  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>usi.servlet.Servlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>


  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Servlet</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

On all of this I get :  `The requested resource () is not available.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, the problem was that I've had JS,CSS and other stuff under the WEB-INF folder, which is inaccessible from outside, when I moved the JS folder a level higher it started working

[image: The new Location of static folder]

The new Location of static folder

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<script type="text/javascript"   src="<c:url value="/static/js/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"/>"></script>
```

Comment: the servlet-mapping is missing from your web.xml ?

Comment: what should I set it to? I've tried : 
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/WebContent/WEB-INF/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

Comment: for example, <servlet-mapping> 
   <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name> 
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping> but I dont know what you do in that servlet nor if you have other servlets that should also be mapped

Comment: <url-pattern>/WebContent/WEB-INF/</url-pattern> , it means the user would have to type something like http://yourserver/WeContent/WEB-INF to access your servlet ...

Comment: I went with <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> which is what I want, but still no luck with the resources

Comment: add mapping for your static content, for example: <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132052/servlet-for-serving-static-content

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39247/discussion-between-q99-and-frederic-close)