# Where to place static files within a javaee-api maven-project

Tags: java, maven, java-ee-7, wildfly-8

Situation: I installed Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler) with the JBoss Tools and added the WildFly 8.0 Application Server. Then I created [a simple JavaEE7-HelloWorld pom.xml](https://github.com/boldt/JavaEE7_HelloWorld/blob/master/pom.xml), for maven-support. I included this pom.xml in Eclipse. I see the JavaEE project structure.

Problem: I want to add some static file (e.g., html, images and css) to that project. I tried everything, but I can't find the correct place to put the static files.

Comment: Probably didn't actually try everything, then. In Maven, web app resources go in `src/main/webapp`. http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: Then you probably have something configured incorrectly. Are you using an Eclipse Maven plugin of some sort? If not, you'll need to define the web artifact stuff yourself.

Comment: Yes, it does work. So if it is not working for you, obviously there is something wrong with your setup and you need to investigate. Might be that the deployment assembly is fudged up for example.

Comment: I just reimported the pom.xml; now the folder `src/main/webapp` was created and an `index.html` is working now. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure a servlet to serve static content, and then put your static content into the directory you specify.

Here's a question with some good examples:
[Servlet for serving static content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132052/servlet-for-serving-static-content)

You have deploy and app to your app server that knows how to serve static content.

Comment: If I create a "Dynamic Web Project" in Eclipse (without maven), then I can simple add the static content to the `WebContent` folder, which does not exist within the maven project..