# JAX-RS: is there a way to handle only certain endpoints RESTfully without rewrite rules?

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have a class that extends JAX-RS' Application. Its ApplicationPath is currently "/", however this overrides all requests from the root, which sucks because I have a lot of other servlets listed in web.xml that I don't want to handle with REST. I'd like to gradually move these existing endpoints over to JAX-RS, but all examples I've seen would imply that I can't selectively handle endpoints like this without URL rewrite rules on the server.

I would like to move these endpoints as such without having to rename them, i.e. without having to change /stuff/list to /rest/stuff/list.

Is there any other way? I'm using RESTeasy as my provider. It has a **resteasy.resources** web.xml parameter option with which I can specify my resources manually, but an Application with an ApplicationPath is still needed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30180337/995891 sounds quite good

Comment: Looks like using RESTeasy as a servlet filter is deprecated in the docs, I really don't know why. That may be my only option though..