# Serving static resources with ServletContainer as Servlet

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey

I noticed that `org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer` is required to be used as `Filter` (setting `spring.jersey.type=filter` in spring boot's `application.properties`) instead than as a `Servlet` in order to provide access to static resources (e.g. `/static/somefile.jsp`, `/static/myfile.css`).

Since I am forced to use `ServletContainer` as a `Servlet`, is there any workaround to allow static resources with this limitation?

Comment: _"...is there any workaround..."_. Change your app root path to something other than the default `/*`. Just annotate your ResourceConfig subclass with something like `@ApplicationPath("/api")`.

Comment: @peeskillet thank you for your hint, it does work indeed, but unfortunately I can't proceed on this road because I can't change the existing urls

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to use [Jersey's MVC feature](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/mvc.html) to server up the JSPs. This doesn't require a filter. For the other static content, you would need to create resource methods for them. For this you would also need to produce your own caching headers, so the brower caches them.

Comment: The problem is not with it being a servlet or a filter, but it's a problem with the `/*`. This hogs up all the request. This is not a limitation of Jersey, but of servlets in general. Where normally the default servlet would serve up the static content from the root, when you specify Jersey to use the root, the static content can't be accessed. The _solution_ is to use Jersey as a filter, that forwards the request to the servlet container, when it can't find the static content path within the Jersey application

Comment: @peeskillet Do you mean mapping each static resource to a method of a controller? If yes, I thought about that but that seems unpractical since I have a lot of files. I'll have a look at Jersey's MVC for jsp and I can always put images, js and css on another server

Comment: Resource paths can use regex, e.g. `@Path("{file: (*.js|*.css)}")`, if that makes it easier

Comment: You might also want to [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/837020/2587435) in an `ExceptionMapper` for NotFoundException. I've never tried it, but I could see it working. When Jersey can't find a resource, it will throw a NotFoundException. You can try to forward the request yourself to the default servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used the first solution provided by @peeskillet

I annotated my `ResourceConfig` subclass with `@ApplicationPath("/v1")`, and managed to keep the endpoint unchanged: luckily they were all defined as `@Path("/v1/endpoint1`)", `@Path("/v1/endpoint2")`, etc. so I removed */v1* from their `@Path` (e.g. `@Path("/endpoint1")`, and they are still  accessible at their original address (e.g. `/v1/endpoint1` ) thanks to the `@ApplicationPath` prefix `/v1`.