# Multiple web WAR application with common resources

Tags: java, tomcat, war

I currently have 3 separated web applications (WAR) successfully deployed into Tomcat. These 3 web apps now need a common header, footer, CSS, JavaScript, and other resources like images. The header has links to the 3 apps, and I am going to add a few more web applications, so I want to maintain 1 menu link list instead of multiple menu link lists individually.

I suggested using a web portal but that was rejected because it is too expensive and not easy to maintain. In fact, the nature of our applications is not well suited for a portal environment.

What option do I have instead of a portal?

Comment: with a portal you're moving the complexity to another level - and you can concentrate your working time on providing business value instead of trying to trick the appserver to share resources, doing identity management, etc. - Your call if you go that route or not. However, "how do I design XY?" is not a good fit for stackoverflow. This site is rather for very concrete questions, rather than general purpose software design recommendation.

Comment: SErve static resources from a static servlet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132052/servlet-for-serving-static-content?rq=1