# JS libraries in IntelliJ are not picked up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intellij-idea

I am creating an NDV3 AngularJS graph demo with IntelliJ.

I have created a standard html file (index.html) and added all the necessary AngularJS and NDV3 libraries in a folder (bower_components) within the resources folder (defined as resource).

I have then added all the required code inside the html file, including
the aforementioned libraries via script tags.

When I run the application however the screen is blank, meaning that the libraries haven't been picked up somehow.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: as this is a java project, you have to configure your resource folder into web.xml or into servlet.xml file

Comment: can you give me a quick example on how this should be defined in the web.xml?

Answer (score 1):

I have create and test an app just like your..

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="phonecat">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Google Phone Gallery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <script src="/resources/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  <script src="/resources/bower_components/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

it works for me..

Problem lies into your java script file src attribute, it is not pointed properly to js file

```
<script src="resources/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

change into

```
<script src="/resources/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

i beleive you problem will be solved

Comment: Hi Jaihrul, I have just realized that AngularJS works fine, it's picked up correctly. The centre of the problem lies in the NVD3-based libraries, somehow they are not picked up. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check following link

[static file mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870150/how-to-access-static-resources-when-mapping-a-global-front-controller-servlet-on)

[another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132052/servlet-for-serving-static-content)

```
<servlet>       
  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>         
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>     
</servlet> 

<servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I do get the HTTP Status 404 page

Comment: i changed the url mapping

Comment: I get the following error:
SEVERE: Error while attempting to validate required application extensions
java.io.IOException: invalid header field

Comment: can u share your web.xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
   <display-name>AccellerationGraph</display-name>
    <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>/index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>